# How to sort the dictionary values in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a dictionary of DateTime and I want to sort the values of the dictionary either in ascending or in descending order. I can do that using long procedure but I know there may be some inbuilt methods are there to sort them. Please suggest the shortest way to sort these dictionary values.

Dictionary that I'm using is

```
    Dictionary<string, DateTime> dict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this *in a dictionary, as a dictionary is unordered (or rather, the ordering can change, and is an implementation detail). You can get an ordered sequence of the pairs though very easily with LINQ:

```
var ordered = dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value); // To order by DateTime value
```

or

```
var ordered = dict.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key); // To order by String key
```

You can then iterate over `ordered` however you want. Use `OrderByDescending` to impose a descending order instead of ascending.

Alternatively, if you want a collection which *maintains* ordering automatically, you could use [`SortedList<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [`SortedDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) if (and only if) you want to sort by key. I don't believe there's any dictionary-like collection in .NET which sorts by *value*.

Comment: But how to sort in descending order?

Comment: @AmitKumar: Use `OrderByDescending` instead. (I've edited my answer to indicate that.)

Answer (score 0):

In descending order, sorting can be done using following statement

```
var ordered = dict.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro. You answer is also right but I can accept only one.